# ng-model reflecting to child scopes as long as no direct input given to child ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Please have a look at https://plnkr.co/edit/j6S9pKL8sLVdSZNFNe9z?p=preview

```
<body >
    <h4>Try me </h4> <input  placeholder="top box" ng-model='address' />
    <div ng-controller="ToddlerCtrl">
      <h4>Try me </h4> 
      <input placeholder="box2" ng-model='address'  /> - {{address}}
      <input placeholder="box3"  ng-model='address' />
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="otherCtrl">
      <h4>Try me </h4> 
      <input placeholder="box4" ng-model='address'  /> - {{address}}
      <input placeholder="box5"  ng-model='address' />
    </div>
```

Box 2,3 are bound to each other it makes sense.
Box 4,5 are bound to each other it makes sense.

But first input box is bound to all others, and it keeps bound only **as long as we do not type something directly in its following boxes**.

The one who is directly provided a value looses its binding to top box.

**I am unable to break binding of top (first) box with others, without typing something in it following boxes, keeping its model name same (address) and keeping the first box at same scope**

Comment: It is because address i first input is binded to the parent controllers scope. So any change in parent will reflect the child

Comment: No, sorry..  It looses binding when directly typed in child..2. In last link I am using no parent controller

Comment: No controller is associated with first input. Assigning a controller to first input will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `ng-controller` form body to another div to make each binding different. Now each binding will be happening in the scope of each controllers. If you nest controllers, the parent scopes value will be reflected in the scopes of the child controller. This is one way to do it by maintaining the same `ng-model` names. Alternative will be change to the name of the model for parent controller `outerCtrl` to something else

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller='outerCtrl'>
         <h4>Try me </h4> <input  placeholder="top box" ng-model='address' />
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="ToddlerCtrl">
      <h4>Try me </h4> 
      <input placeholder="box2" ng-model='address'  /> - {{address}}
      <input placeholder="box3"  ng-model='address' />
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="otherCtrl">
      <h4>Try me </h4> 
      <input placeholder="box4" ng-model='address'  /> - {{address}}
      <input placeholder="box5"  ng-model='address' />
    </div>

  </body>
```

**Update**:

When you type something in the first input irrespective of the input being inside a controller or not(for your case) , the value will bind to `$scope.$parent` and that is reflected across everywhere. But if you change the `ng-model` for your controllers, the binding is happening in `$scope` of that controller. Now the value of address in `$scope` and `$scope.$parent` are different and any change in $scope of a controller won't affect the parent scope.

**Updated Demo**: https://plnkr.co/edit/xG6nY8yTR3AoNkeHex0E?p=preview

Comment: Sorry i do not want to deglobalize it. Because this case is already solved. You can see the demo that wrapped boxes are not bound to out of their scope. You please type first in 2nd box and see global bind will be lost without deglobalizing. Why this thing can not be achieved without typing in floowing boxes

Comment: Your help is appreciable, thanks for this but from very first edit I had written very clear that I have three groups of ng-models, two already fine. Top one looses binding as soon as we type in following boxes.

Comment: @Sami  I have updated my answer. I hope i have answered it correctly now :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/basics/nestedcontrollers/

Defining variables directly on the $scope objects managed by the controllers can have unexpected behaviors if we don't know how AngularJS works.

Working with object variables:https://plnkr.co/edit/mQDFg2pM5u3cjuhDgha4?p=preview

    Try me  
    
      Try me  
       - {{address}}

```
<div ng-controller="otherCtrl">
  <h4>Try me </h4> 
  <input placeholder="box4" ng-model='firstModelObj.address'  /> - {{address}}
  <input placeholder="box5"  ng-model='firstModelObj.address' />
</div>
```